# Type error undefined not a function - Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, undefined, collision-detection, typeerror, fabricjs

I'm receiving this error after attempting to optimise some code I'm working on.

Initially I was using `canvas.forEachObject(function(obj){})` which was working fine but I needed to streamline the process somewhat.

I now have a function that iterates through the canvas and adds all the relevant object type to an array that I will then use.

```
function getObjects(){

    var canvasObjects = canvas.getObjects();
    var theArray = new Array();

    for(obj in canvasObjects){
        if(canvasObjects[obj].get('type') == 'thisType'){
            theArray.push(canvasObjects[obj]);
        }

        if(canvasObjects[obj].get('type') == 'group'){
            var groupObjects = canvasObjects[obj].getObjects();
            for(groupObj in groupObjects){
                if(groupObjects[groupObj].get('type') == 'thisType'){
                    theArray.push(groupObjects[groupObj]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return theArray;
}
```

I'm then calling a function in an animation loop that uses the array in order to determine if a collision has occurred.

Array created here:

```
var geoArray = getObjects();

function detectCollision(target) {

    target.setCoords();

    geoArray.forEachObject(function(obj)
    //for(obj in geoArray) //1st attempt - same result
    {
        obj.setCoords();
        if(obj!=target && target.intersectsWithObject(obj)){
            //..do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

The array is built fine and contains the correct number of objects so I'm sure there is no problem there. The problem occurs when I run the collision function and the type error problem occurs.  Searching indicates that I may not be returning the object type but I'm not sure if this is the case and if so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Many thanks for any help.

Edit: the exact error is:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'geoArray.forEachObject')
```

Edit, the error occurs always within the collision loop and as soon as 'obj' is called.

Comment: which line has the error?

Comment: Where's geoArray assigned?

Comment: sorry, I renamed the variables to make things 'clearer' - fail. I've edited the question

Comment: @ppoliani: Question updated, hope that makes things clearer

Comment: @GrandmasterB: Question updated, hope that makes things clearer

Comment: `var geoArray = getObjectsForCollision();` I don't see a function named `getObjectsForcollision`...

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit more on this sentence  "Edit, the error occurs always within the collision loop and as soon as 'obj' is called.". What do you mean as soon as obj is called? obj is not a function...

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj - Apologies, I renamed functions and variables to try and make things clearer and I seem to have only added confusion.  Apologies-lesson learnt

Comment: I think there is still confusion, the getObjects function appears to have a plethora of naming errors. If it doesn't then your problem certainly lies in that function. I see arrays being used without being declared, empty arrays being accessed, etc.

Comment: @ppoliani - I did some further checks.  The error occurs at this line: geoArray.forEachObject(function(obj)

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger to be sure that geoArray is visible and valid inside that function?

Comment: @GrandmasterB - No debugger as such - I've tested the array is visible by a simple console.log("Array? "+geoArray.length); called inside the function.  It returns the correct value so I assume the array is accessible and valid.

Comment: If the error occurs at the line you mentioned then it means that forEachObject is undefined. Which debugger are you using?

Comment: There's (quite good) debuggers built into every major browser.  I would check that forEachObject is in fact a valid method.  I don't think thats a standard javascript method on arrays.  I think you might want just forEach.

Comment: @ppoliani - you're incredible, thank you!  Thank you everyone.  I changed to forEach instead of forEachObject and it works fine. :)

Comment: @GrandmasterB - thank you also, I was using the safari console for the majority of debugging. You are also correct in say the forEachObject was incorrect.  Thank you for your time! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're using to iterate through the array is not correct. The `forEachObject` is not a method of a plain JavaScript Array. It is a method defined on `fabric.Collection`.

The error simply indicates that you trying to use an undefined type as a function; You can either iterate using the `forEach` method or using a common `for` loop.

Comment: thanks for your earlier help and for posting the solution, much appreciation to both yourself and @GrandmasterB.